# Mail, Contacts & Calendars refuses to connect to Google

Tags: mail.app, calendar, contacts, gmail

Since yesterday the System Preferences pane on Mail, Contacts & Calendars refuses to connect to Google to setup e-mail, calendars and contacts. It started after Contacts.app did not want to sync with Google Contacts and asked and refused my correct password. After that Mail.app and Calendar.app did the same. I removed the account from System Preferences and attempted to start anew.

However, now it throws the following error at me:

[image]

Nowhere in any log I know can I find more information on the error. When I monitor the connection using Little Snitch it shows that the following connections are attempted:

[image]

I can ping them all through Terminal.app successfully.

I have no 2-step verification, so I'm not using application specific passwords in Google.

This is what I've tried, all without a positive outcome:

- Add a Gmail account in the Guest user (same error).
- Make a new Gmail account, try to add it (same error).
- Enable 2-step verification, make application specific passwords (same error).
- Run Keychain first aid.
- Verify & Repair permissions.
- Verify & Repair disk (volume bitmap needed minor repair for orphaned blocks). After repair still the same situation.
- Reverted `/etc/hosts` file to default.
- Disabled Little Snitch.
- Boot from external drive into Yosemite, try to add the Google account.
- Try connection through ethernet instead of airport express.
- Try connection through a different network entirely.
- Following the [troubleshooting steps](https://support.google.com/accounts/troubleshooter/3178296?hl=en&ref_topic=3382297) from Google.
- [Allowing "less secure application"](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) (that still use OAuth 1.0) to login to Google.
- [Resetting the Keychain](http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/display/istcontrib/Create+a+new+login+or+reset+Keychain+for+Mac+OS+X)

I've really exhausted my Google-fu and little knowledge I have on Macs. I would really appreciate some pointers on where to look further.

Comment: Sounds rather elementary but have you tried restarting the system?

Comment: Yes, several times :) I've had to do a disk repair (restart necessary) and booted from an external drive (into Yosemite).

Comment: @BartArondson:: I just posted the same question - I had to setup a gmail account on Mavericks on the weekend and got the same error message. Finally I did it by using the Other Account option: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/189685/setting-up-gmail-in-mavericks-a-connection-error-occurred

Comment: @FFrewin while its a workaround (which I use now as well, thank you), it doesn't really solve the problem. It should just simply work as it did a couple of days back. I'll keep looking for a solution.

Comment: @BartArondson:: I know it's a workaround. I was also unable to find any references for this issue. Maybe Google is able to answer this one. Remember to post back if you find anything - also on my question so i will get notified.

Comment: I almost like to reverse questions like this. Take all the body and research and make the question. I get this specific error on this specific software when following this guide... Then have all the troubleshooting explained in the answer. Let's see what comes of this and the similar question with an answer at http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/189685/

Comment: @bmike I'm not quite sure I understand. Should I make the troubleshooting steps I've followed into an answer and remove the from the question?

Comment: Your call totally. If you're looking for assistance troubleshooting, the shorter you make the question, the more participation you'll get. Something that long, people just tune out and hope you'll post an answer later. When I make a minimal question and then show my troubleshooting in an answer, all sorts of people will show up to explain how I "did it wrong" and usually they are right and have a fix.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Gmail help forum thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/vdU4sr6vMM4) this is an issue that is fixed in Mac OS 10.10.3. There user jbrandtAUS writes on the 29th of May:

> From others I have talked to, starting yesterday, people have not been able to add their Gmail accounts to Mail or System Preferences > Internet Accounts if they have 10.10.1 or 10.10.2... if you update to 10.10.3 it will work

So the solution is to upgrade to anything above Mac OS 10.10.2.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a viable solution or me as I rely on the Syncservices framework in Mountain Lion. This framework is not present anymore in OS 10.10

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, open connection doctor in Mail and enable logging. There are about a dozen log files in addition to what goes to the main log.

If you can Then add the wrong account anyway and then use Mail's connection doctor to inspect the traffic and then determine what error you have specifically. Unless there's a console log listing the error, you're going to have a hard time knowing which error is happening when and if it’s network or configuration or software incompatibility issues.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I simply cannot add a Gmail account through the Mail, Contact & Calendars pane, so neither can I check the traffic in Mail.